# Remove class when window is resized

Tags: jquery, resize

First I say, what I need to get as a result.

I need to, when window width is more than 500px, in my navigation menu added class "fixed". When window width is less than 500px, from that navigation menu class "fixed" was removed.

This example working with $(window).ready(), but with $(window).resize() class "fixed" is't removing, when window is less than 500px. I'm confused.. What problem? Thanks in advance

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evv7d/3/)

```
function navigation() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if ( windowWidth > 500 ) {
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            var menuFixed = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (menuFixed > 300) {
                $('.nav').addClass('fixed');
            } else {
                $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
}

$(window).ready(function(){
    navigation();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    navigation();
});
```

Comment: Media queries boy, media queries.

Comment: On each window resize, you are rebinding a new document scroll handler. Your logic is failing. Better would be to use media queries and if you need to support IE8, then use some shim/workaround. Just google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this with CSS3

```
@media max-width 500px {
.menuFixed { position: fixed;}
}
```

[Refer to Mozilla ♥ for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)